# Vue Composition Reactive properties are not updating in components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I'm building out a notification system and it's sorta working, but sorta not. I have the follow Composition function

```
const data = reactive({
    notifications: []
});
let notificationKey = 0;

export const useNotification = () => {
    const visibleNotifications = computed(() => {
        return data.notifications.slice().reverse();
    });

    const add = (notification: INotification) => {
        notification.key  = notificationKey++;
        notification.type = notification.type ?? 'success';

        notification.icon      = iconObject[notification.type];
        notification.iconColor = iconColorObject[notification.type];
        data.notifications.push(notification);

        notificationTimer[notification.key] = new Timer(() => {
            remove(notification.key);
        }, notificationTimeout);
    };

    const remove = (notificationKey: number) => {
        const notificationIndex = data.notifications.findIndex(notification => notification?.key === notificationKey);
        if (notificationTimer[notificationKey] !== undefined) {
            notificationTimer[notificationKey].stop();
        }
        if (notificationIndex > -1) {
            data.notifications.splice(notificationIndex, 1);
        }
    };

    const click = (notification: INotification) => {
       /// ... click code 
    };

    return {
        visibleNotifications,
        add,
        remove,
        click
    };
};
```

This is working (It's been simplified a little bit). Now, I have two entry points in Webpack. In one entry point (auth), I have the following code to load up a Vue Component for showing the Notification

```
 Promise.all([
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "Vue"*/ 'vue'),
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "@vue/composition-api"*/ '@vue/composition-api'),
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "Notifications"*/'components/Notifications.vue')
]).then((
    [
        { default: Vue },
        { default: VueCompositionAPI },
        { default: Notifications },
    ]) => {
    Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI);

    new Vue({
        render: h => h(Notifications)
    }).$mount('.notification-outer);
});
```

Now, this all works, and I add in there the following code

```
import { useNotification } from 'modules/compositionFunctions/notifications';
useNotification().add({
    title  : 'Error',
    message: 'This is an error notification',
    type   : 'error',
});
```

Then the notification shows as expected[image: notification image] This is all happening inside the "auth" entry point, and the above is all typescript.

Now, if I go to my second entry point (editor), and in an existing JS file enter the following code

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: "useNotification"*/ 'modules/compositionFunctions/notifications').then(({ useNotification }) => {
    useNotification().add({
        title     : 'Block Deleted',
        message   : 'The block has been deleted',
        buttonText: 'Undo',
        buttonFunction () {
            undoDelete();
        }
    });
});
```

Then it "works", and by this I mean, all of the code from the useNotification function works. The add method will add it, (if I console log out the reactive property), and after 15000ms, the remove methods happens and I can add logs to show that. HOWEVER, the Vue component never sees this change. If I add a watch in the Vue Component, and log out as we go, the first notification (image above) will make JS log to the console, however, when adding it from the "editor" entry point, it won't do anything.

Vue Component JS

```
import { useNotification } from 'modules/compositionFunctions/notifications';
import { defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api';

export default defineComponent({
    name : 'Notifications',
    setup () {
        const { visibleNotifications, remove, click: notificationClick } = useNotification();

        return {
            visibleNotifications,
            remove,
            notificationClick,
        };
    },
    watch: {
        visibleNotifications: (v) => {
            console.log(v);
        }
    }
});
```

PLEASE, someone, tell me they can help? This is starting to do my head in...

TIA

Comment: can you provide a demo in codesandbox??

Comment: Can you show code of `remove` method ?

Comment: @tuhin47 - I don't THINK so? It's a full Webpack setup with multiple endpoints which I don't think is possible in Codepen.

Comment: @KrzysztofKaczyński I don't think that the remove method is the issue as the `data` contains has everything in there when I log it out. Added it in the above anyway

Comment: Could you confirm that the `Notifications` component is actually rendered somewhere when you're using the editor entry point? Also, could you try putting console logging right at the top of your `notifications.ts` to confirm that the file only gets pulled in once (to confirm `data.notifications` is unique). Assuming neither of those is the problem, could you maybe put a stripped back, buildable, runnable version of your application on GitHub so we can try it ourselves?

Comment: I'll give those a go in the morning and post the results back

Comment: @LeeR I think there can be a problem with remove method. Can you try my answer and let me know is it works ?

Comment: I've updated my code above to how now I have it. I no longer use the `visible` key to determine whether to show the notification or not. I simply just add or remove the notification from the array to ensure the reactivity

Comment: @skirtle. Repo found here: https://github.com/leereichardt/vue-composition-entry-points. If you run `npm ci`, then `npm start`, then open `dist/index.html` in a browser, you should be good to go. Interestingly, in this case, I have code in both entry1 and entry2 and sometimes 1 will work and 2 won't, or 2 will work and 1 won't but I can't find any reason on what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code provided in the GitHub repo, I added some console logging immediately before this part:

```js
window.notifications = reactive({
   notifications: []
});
```

The logging was called twice. Once from `entry1.hash.bundle.js` and once from `entry2.hash.bundle.js`.

My understanding of Webpack is limited but it would seem that it is building those two entry-points to be self-contained and isn't expecting you to run both of them on the page at the same time.

I would have thought it would be possible to extract all the notification stuff to its own shared chunk, a bit like the vendors bundle. That said, I'm not really clear why you're using two entry-points rather than two chunks. My understanding is that entry-points should be one-per-page and then you split them up using chunks.

All that said, there is a quick hack to get it working:

```js
if (!window.notifications) {
    window.notifications = reactive({
        notifications: []
    });
}
```

This ensures that the same array is being shared no matter how many times it gets run.

I should stress that I don't advocate the use of such a hack in production code. It just kicks the Webpack problems further down the road and pollutes the global namespace in the process. It does help to confirm what the problem is though.

Comment: The reason we are using two entry points is that we have various parts of our entire application. Previously these were all separate files to load when they are in editor/auth/logged out, etc. My aim is to eventually use chunks for this, but we brought Webpack into a legacy system and unfortunately, it has to be done this way. BUT! This has solved the issue, so now to figure out how to get it only loading the chunk once as to not overwrite the files! Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

what i infer from your code is that, your components are tightly coupled. and i suggest that follow a more object oriented approach like user->data->notification->seen and so on. that might need a slight restructuring of your existing code (and or) in database.

i would also suggest you that have a look at firebase ([FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging)). a notification system. firebase is a google product, can  trust their methodology.(not promoting it but the way they implement the notification system is absolutely scalable)

but if its a completely self developed app and does not want to rely on third party, then the next best move is using the "notify on change" method.

a rough overview will be like this.

- some event in database/app (to which the user needs to be notified) happens
- trace what the event does to affected users[scope of the event]
- built a notifier object[some json file] stored in database or plain json, for example **notif.json**
- now send that to the user once they are active.

you can check if they are active or not by setInterval() function on client side.
and once they are active check the notif.json and if it has a pending notification push it to user and delete that entry from file or DB.

rule of thumb is don't waste time in existing code if its not working, sometimes rewriting in different approach saves more time.

Comment: It's a fully self-developed app where we don't want to rely too much on outside libraries for this, also just for clarification, the notifications are less "push" notifications where we deliver and wait for them to be seen, and more real-time notifications that show as they're interacting with the web app itself.

Comment: oh haha, never mind, i intended to give some ideas and how i personally implement. looks like my answer added no value. :-E